# Считывание чисел и букв из файла

Tags: c, строки

Такая проблема, в файле есть числа и символы, числа больше чем один знак, поэтому как символы считать не могу, а символы как числа не чикаются, как мне считать число, если это число и символ, если это символ, данные записаны в одну строчку через пробелы.

Comment: Цифры, из которых состоят числа - тоже, знаешь ли, символы, когда в текстовом файле...

Comment: Я понимаю, но мне нужно считать их именно как числа, но символы считать как символы

Comment: Регуляркой почистить от символов, оставив одни цифири, а потом конвертировать в число... например.

Comment: Мне нужно именно подряд их считывать

Comment: Ну тады считывай по одному символу... цифра? в буфер... не цифра? символ отбросить, буфер преобразовать в число и отправить по назначению (если буфер не пустой), буфер почистить, перейти к следующему символу.

Comment: Мне символы тоже нужны, это знаки операций сложения и т.д., я пробовал читать fscanf, %d, так он не читает знаки операций вообще, какой функцией тогда это читать?

Comment: fgets считывайте строку ,а  strtok разбивайте по пробелам.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, тема вашей лабы звучит так: "Написать программу, вычисляющую значение выражения, состоящего из чисел и знаков операций". И, уверяю Вас, здесь есть вопросы посложнее ввода чисел из символьной строки. Например: А скобки в выражениях допускаются?.  А приоритет операций есть? А выражение может занимать несколько строк?


Т.е., на самом деле, Вам нужно сделать:

- Разбить строку на лексемы

- Построить дерево синтаксического разбора 

- Построить обратную польскую запись

- ОПЗ преобразовать в код абстрактного ассемблера

- Выполнить полученную программу

Comment: Уже в постфиксной форме, буду вычислять на стеке.

Comment: Конечный автомат забабахайте, и будет вам счастье

Answer (score 0):

Можно составить конечный автомат с следующей конфигурацией:

- Алфавит - цифра (0-9), знак (+,-), операция (*,/), пробел (пробел и пробельные символы по типу `\t` `\n`), конец файла (EOF)
- Состояния - начальное, конечное (конец файла), ошибка в синтаксисе, ввода числа, ввод операции, ввод знака,
- Таблица переходов, описывающая переходу между состояниями по символу алфавита.

Пример:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef enum{
    ELeftIsNotNumber = 1,
    ERightIsNotNumber = 2,
    EStackIsEmpty = 3
}ErrorType;

//Состояния
typedef enum{
    SStart = 0,         //начальное
    SNumber = 1,        //число
    SSpace = 2,         //пробел (перевод строки, таб, и т.п.)
    SOperation1 = 3,    //сложение вычитание
    SOperation2 = 4,    //умножение деление
    SEnd = 5,           //конечное
    SSyntaxError = 6    //конечное
}State;

int isFinishState(State s);

//Типы символов
typedef enum{
    STDigit = 0,        // 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
    STSign = 1,         // '+', '-'
    STOperation  = 2,   // '*', '/'
    STSpace = 3,        // ' '
    STEOF = 4,          // EOF
    STUnknow = 5        //any other symbol
}SymbolType;

// Таблица переходов между состояниями по символам алфавита
int StateMachineTransitions[5][6] = {
//  STDigit      STSign       STOperation   STSpace  STEof  STUnknow
  { SNumber,     SOperation1, SSyntaxError, SSpace,  SEnd,  SSyntaxError},   //SStart
  { SNumber,     SSyntaxError,SSyntaxError, SSpace,  SEnd,  SSyntaxError},   //SNumber
  { SNumber,     SOperation1, SOperation2,  SSpace,  SEnd,  SSyntaxError},   //SSpace
  { SNumber,     SSyntaxError,SSyntaxError, SSpace,  SEnd,  SSyntaxError},   //SOp1
  { SSyntaxError,SSyntaxError,SSyntaxError, SSpace,  SEnd,  SSyntaxError}    //SOp2
};

//Определить типа символа из алфавита
SymbolType getType(int c);

//Переход к следующему состоянию
State nextState(State s, int c){
    return StateMachineTransitions[s][getType(c)];
}

//Тип операции
typedef enum{
    OpAdd = 0,
    OpSub = 1,
    OpMult = 2,
    OpDiv = 3
}Operation;

//Тип лексемы - число, операция
typedef enum{
    LexNumber = 0,
    LexOperation = 1
}LexType;

//Лексема - число или операция
typedef struct{
    LexType type;
    union{
        int number;
        Operation operation;
    }value;
}Lexema;

Lexema createNumber(int n);
Lexema createOperation(Operation op);

//Узел списка
//Также список исользуется как стэк
typedef struct{
    Lexema data;
    struct Node* next;
    struct Node* prev;
}Node;

Node* createNode(Lexema lex);


typedef struct{
    Node* first;
    Node* last;
}List;

List* createList();
List* pushList(List* l, Lexema lex);
List* popList(List* l);
int  emptyList(List* l);
Lexema topList(List* l);
void destroyList(List* l);

List* parseLexemsFromFile(const char* filePath);

Lexema calcOperation(Lexema left, Lexema right, Lexema op);

int main(void)
{
    List* listOfLexems = parseLexemsFromFile("example.txt");
    List* stack = createList();
    Node* cur = listOfLexems->first;
    while (cur != NULL){
        if (cur->data.type == LexNumber){
            stack = pushList(stack, cur->data);
        }
        if (cur->data.type == LexOperation){
            if (emptyList(stack)){
                fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: stack is empty");
                exit(EStackIsEmpty);
            }
            Lexema right = topList(stack);
            stack = popList(stack);
            if (emptyList(stack)){
                fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: stack is empty");
                exit(EStackIsEmpty);
            }
            Lexema left = topList(stack);
            stack = popList(stack);
            Lexema result = calcOperation(left, right, cur->data);
            stack = pushList(stack, result);
        }
        cur = (Node*)cur->next;
    }
    destroyList(listOfLexems);
    if (!emptyList(stack) && topList(stack).type == LexNumber){
        printf("result: %d\n", topList(stack).value.number);
    }
    destroyList(stack);
    return 0;
}

Lexema createLexema(LexType type, char* buf){
    Lexema ret;
    ret.type = type;
    if (type == LexOperation){
        switch (buf[0]) {
        case '+':
            ret.value.operation = OpAdd;
            break;
        case '-':
            ret.value.operation = OpSub;
            break;
        case '*':
            ret.value.operation = OpMult;
            break;
        case '/':
            ret.value.operation = OpDiv;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
    if (type == LexNumber){
        sscanf(buf, "%d", &(ret.value.number));
    }
    return ret;
}

int isFinishState(State s){
    if (s == SEnd || s == SSyntaxError){
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}


List* parseLexemsFromFile(const char* filePath){
    List* lexems = createList();
    FILE* f = fopen(filePath, "r");
    if (f == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "file %s do not exist\n", filePath);
        return lexems;
    }
    char buf[512];
    int bufSize = 0;
    State s = SStart;
    do{
        int c = fgetc(f);
        State lastState = s;
        s = nextState(s, c);
        switch (s) {
        case SNumber:
        case SOperation1:
        case SOperation2:
            buf[bufSize] = c;
            bufSize++;
            break;
        case SSpace:
        case SEnd:
            buf[bufSize] = '\0';
            bufSize = 0;
            if (lastState == SNumber){
                lexems = pushList(lexems, createLexema(LexNumber, buf));
            }
            if (lastState == SOperation1 ||
                lastState == SOperation2){
                lexems = pushList(lexems, createLexema(LexOperation, buf));
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }while(!isFinishState(s));
    fclose(f);
    if (s == SSyntaxError){
        fprintf(stderr, "Syntax error!!!\n");
        destroyList(lexems);
        lexems = createList();
    }
    return lexems;
}

Lexema calcOperation(Lexema left, Lexema right, Lexema op){
    int ret = 0;
    if (left.type != LexNumber){
        fprintf(stderr, "left operand is not number\n");
        exit(ELeftIsNotNumber);
    }
    if (right.type != LexNumber){
        fprintf(stderr, "right operand is not number\n");
        exit(ERightIsNotNumber);
    }
    switch (op.value.operation) {
    case OpAdd:
        ret = left.value.number + right.value.number;
        break;
    case OpSub:
        ret = left.value.number - right.value.number;
        break;
    case OpMult:
        ret = left.value.number * right.value.number;
        break;
    case OpDiv:
        if (right.value.number != 0){
            ret = left.value.number / right.value.number;
        }else{
            fprintf(stderr, "divide by zero !!!\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    default:
        break;
    }
    return createNumber(ret);
}

/*
 *
 *  List implementation
 *
 *
 */
Node* createNode(Lexema lex){
    Node* ret = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    ret->next = NULL;
    ret->prev = NULL;
    memcpy((void*)(&(ret->data)), (void*)(&lex), sizeof(Lexema));
    return ret;
}


List* createList(){
    List* ret = (List*) malloc(sizeof(List));
    ret->first = NULL;
    ret->last = NULL;
    return ret;
}


List* pushList(List* l, Lexema lex){
    if (l == NULL){
        return l;
    }
    if (l->first == NULL){
        //empty list
        l->first = createNode(lex);
        l->last = l->first;
    }else{
        Node* lastNode = createNode(lex);
        lastNode->prev = (struct Node*)l->last;
        l->last->next = (struct Node*)lastNode;
        l->last = lastNode;
    }
    return l;
}

List* popList(List* l){
    if (l == NULL)
        return l;
    if (l->first == NULL){
        return l;
    }
    if (l->first == l->last){
        //one element in list
        free(l->first);
        l->first = NULL;
        l->last = NULL;
    }else{
        Node* lastNode = l->last;
        l->last = (Node*)(lastNode->prev);
        free(lastNode);
        l->last->next = NULL;
    }
    return l;
}

int  emptyList(List* l){
    if (l == NULL){
        return 1;
    }
    if (l->first == NULL){
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

Lexema topList(List* l){
    Lexema ret;
    if (l == NULL){
        return ret;
    }
    if (l->last == NULL){
        return ret;
    }
    return l->last->data;
}

void destroyList(List* l){
    while (!emptyList(l)){
        l = popList(l);
    }
    if (l != NULL)
        free(l);
    return;
}


SymbolType getType(int c){
    SymbolType ret = STUnknow;
    switch (c) {
    case '*':
    case '/':
        ret = STOperation;
        break;
    case '+':
    case '-':
        ret = STSign;
        break;
    case ' ':
        ret = STSpace;
        break;
    case EOF:
        ret = STEOF;
        break;
    default:
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
            ret = STDigit;
        if (isspace(c)){
            ret = STSpace;
        }
        break;
    }
    return ret;
}

Lexema createNumber(int n){
    Lexema ret;
    ret.type = LexNumber;
    ret.value.number = n;
    return ret;
}
Lexema createOperation(Operation op){
    Lexema ret;
    ret.type = LexOperation;
    ret.value.operation = op;
    return ret;
}
```

Содержимое файла `example.txt` и результат работы программы:

```
motya@motya-ThinkPad-R61:~/qProjects/build-ReadSD-Desktop-Debug$ cat example.txt 
-1 +5 - 6 + 1024 + 256 /


motya@motya-ThinkPad-R61:~/qProjects/build-ReadSD-Desktop-Debug$ ./ReadSD 
result: 4
motya@motya-ThinkPad-R61:~/qProjects/build-ReadSD-Desktop-Debug$
```